# Loop inside highchart in R

Tags: r, loops, highcharts, rstudio, shinydashboard

I have to automatisate the analyse of a dataset on RStudio.

My problem is that  I don't know how many series are going to be in the dataset. So I'm wondering is it possible to do a for loop INSIDE the Highcharts ?

I don't know if it doesn't work because I've done something wrong or because it's not possible.

```
output$hc2 <- renderHighchart ({
Hchc <- highchart(hcaes(x = Spring ,y = Ponctuation)) %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Cumulation of the result of a Team per spring",
           margin = 20, align = "left",
           style = list(color = "#FE8000", useHTML = TRUE)) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = tableA$Spring, title = list(text = "Number of spring",color = "#FE8000")) %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Cumulation of the result", color = "#FE8000"))%>% 

  for (i in length(mylist)){
    hc_add_series(name = name[i], data = mylistcumu[[i]]$CumuPonct) }

print(Hchc)})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found !

```
output$hc2 <- renderHighchart ({
Hchc <- highchart(hcaes(x = Spring ,y = Ponctuation)) %>% 
hc_title(text = "Cumulation of the result of a Team per spring",
           margin = 20, align = "left",
           style = list(color = "#FE8000", useHTML = TRUE)) %>% 
hc_xAxis(categories = tableA$Spring, title = list(text = "Number of spring",color = "#FE8000")) %>%
hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Cumulation of the result", color = "#FE8000"))

for (i in 1:length(mylist)){
  Hchc <- Hchc %>%
   hc_add_series(name = name[i], data = mylistcumu[[i]]$CumuPonct) }

Hchc})
```